# Int Type vs scala.Int Type

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm using scala reflections to get all fields of a case class that are not methods. I then want to see if the type is a primitive type or string (or an option of these things). Here's a simple working example that checks if a field is a String.

```
scala> case class SimpleCase(val1: String)
defined class SimpleCase

scala> val members = typeOf[SimpleCase].members.filter(!_.isMethod).toList
members: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = List(value val1)

scala> members.head.typeSignature
res57: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = String

scala> members.head.typeSignature == typeOf[String]
res58: Boolean = true
```

Works exactly the way that I would expect it to. Here's where things get weird - when I do the same thing with an Int, or any primitive type for that matter, the type checking test fails. Here's an example of said failure:

```
scala> case class SimpleCase(val1: Int)
defined class SimpleCase

scala> val members = typeOf[SimpleCase].members.filter(!_.isMethod).toList
members: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = List(value val1)

scala> members.head.typeSignature
res59: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.Int

scala> members.head.typeSignature == typeOf[Int]
res60: Boolean = false

scala> members.head.typeSignature == typeOf[scala.Int]
res61: Boolean = false
```

Also, typeOf[Int] prints out

```
scala> typeOf[Int]
res62: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Int
```

The type signature of `SimpleCase`'s `val1` states that it is a `scala.Int` rather than `typeOf[Int]`'s type signature, which is `Int`. So I tried comparing `val1` to both `typeOf[Int]` and `typeOf[scala.Int]` (even though I'm pretty sure they're the same thing) to no avail.

What's going on here? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should compare types with `=:=` instead of `==`.

The [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Types.html) says:

> Type Equality can be checked with =:=. It's important to note that == should not be used to compare types for equality-- == can't check for type equality in the presence of type aliases, while =:= can.

Comment: Wow! I was hoping the solution would be that simple. Thank you!